# How to get position of dragged image with respect to the division in which it is dragged?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using a drag drop (jQuery method) with java script. The image is dragged on a another division.
Now I want to know the position of the dragged image with respect to its division where it is dragged.

Comment: Can you give us some code? HTML and JS